# Virtualbox decryption

Tags: virtualbox, vmware

So I had an encryption setup on one of my VMs.(fedora linux) Then fedora asked for software upgrade and it upgraded virtual box.

Now when I am starting machine, instead of asking for encryption password, it goes into PAUSED state and infinitely waits there, which implies guest-addons are missing after virtualbox upgrade.

How can I decrypt this vm so that I can reuse this vm? I want my data back, months of dev on this machine. Any experts on Virtualbox here can answer this?

While decrypting, getting error:

```
VBoxManage encryptmedium --cipher -aes-256-cbc algo2020/algo2020.vdi --oldpassword  algo2020d/pwd.txt 
0%...
Progress state: VBOX_E_NOT_SUPPORTED
VBoxManage: error: Encrypt hard disk operation for this cipher is not implemented yet!
```

pwd.txt contains only the password.

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me is this command:

```
VBoxManage encryptmedium algo2020/algo2020.vdi  --cipher AES-XTS256-PLAIN64   --oldpassword -
```